# Ktor respondTextWriter complaining about inappropriate blocking method call

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm implementing a server using Ktor, and one of the calls is to get a (potentially large) list of users that will come from a database query. I would like to chunk my response, so my user call looks like this:

```
    fun users() =
        flow {
            emit("A")
            emit("B")
            emit("C")
        }
```

Where the emit calls will eventually be replaced with data from a result set. The route looks like this:

```
        route("Users") {
            get() {
                call.respondTextWriter {
                    users().collect { write(it) }
                    flush()
                }
            }
            // other calls, e.g. post(), delete(), etc.
```

However, both calls to `write` and `flush` show a warning: "Inappropriate blocking method call". What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, a little digging provided the answer:

```
private suspend fun <T> flowResponse(writer: Writer, flow: Flow<T>) {
    val gson = Gson()
    flow.collect { data ->
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            writer.write(gson.toJson(data))
        }
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { writer.flush() }
}
```

And then:

```
            get() {
                call.respondTextWriter {
                    flowResponse(this, Users.all())
                }
            }
```

Slight change from the question, as my `Users.all()` call returns a User object that then gets converted to JSON. Perhaps there is a way to simply stream the objects and let the content negotiator do the translation, but I haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: You can hoist the `withContext` outside of the collect, because terminal flow operators execute in the context they were called in.

Comment: If I do that, then it complains that the call to writer.write is an "inappropriate blocking call"

Comment: Seems to be a lack of context information because that should be correct, you can leave the `withContext` inside the `collect` because I'm pretty sure dispatching to the same dispatcher does not cause a context switch.

Comment: That's what I expected, but it's not what the IDE tells me...